# How do I reload a view after a UIAlertView has been closed?

Tags: objective-c, ios

After a UIAlertView is closed, I would like to reload a view (run `viewWillDisappear` for the view and `viewWillAppear` for the view).

How do I do that? I have tried delegating to both nil and self. Here is my code.

```
- (IBAction)doStuffWhenUIButtonIsClicked:(id)sender
{
    int intSelection = [sender tag];
    NSString* strAlertTitle;
    NSString* strAlertMessage;
    if (intSelection == self.intCorrectChoice) {
        strAlertTitle = @"Correct tag!";
    }
    else {
        strAlertTitle = @"Sorry, incorrect tag!";
    }
strAlertMessage = @"The correct answer was 8.";

    self.answerReaction = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle: strAlertTitle
                                 message: strAlertMessage
                                delegate: nil
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Next Question"
                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [self.answerReaction show];
}
```

As you see, I want to load a new question after the user answers one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to make the view controller that you are in conform to the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol.

Then, before you show the alert, you need to add this line:

```
self.answerReaction.delegate = self;
```

Then, implement the didDismissWithButtonIndex delegate method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    [self viewWillDisappear:YES];
    // load your new question
    [self viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

That should take care of it!

Answer (score 0):

just add this method which is triggered when u click any button on UIAlertView.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView  clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        [self viewWillDisappear:YES];
        [self viewWillAppear:YES];
    }
}
```

hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for me! I have:

```
- (IBAction)OkButton:(id)sender {    

  // store your selected row
    NSUInteger selectedRow = [_intervalPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];    

    // Display a message to user
    if (selectedRow == CorrectAnswer) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Correct!" message:@"YAY!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alert show];

        RightScoreNumber0 += 1;
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry!" message:@"Wrong answer" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alert show];

        WrongScoreNumber0 += 1;
    }

}
```

and as you suggested:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"OK was selected");  

    [self viewWillDisappear:YES];
    // load your new question
    [self viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

I get the message "OK was selected", but nothings else happens...

**It finally worked but in another way!!**
I replace both

```
[self viewWillDisappear:YES];
[self viewWillAppear:YES];
```

with

```
[self viewDidLoad];
```